# How to compare two times using php

Tags: php, datetime

I have to compare time with a time value stored in a variable. I have devised the logic but it fails at time.

Following is the logic:

```
$diff = "22:32:53";

if ($diff > strtotime("072:00:00") )
{
    echo "DO A";
}
else if ($diff < strtotime("08:00:00"))
{
    echo "DO B";
}
else if( $diff > strtotime("08:00:00") && $diff < strtotime("072:00:00"))
{
    echo "DO C";
}
```

But it echoes "DO A" whereas it should display "DO C". Could not figure out where I am missing the logic

Thanks in advance.

Comment: strtotime converts a valid date string to a timestamp. strtotime("072:00:00") returns false.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare time (without date), the best way is to manually convert them into seconds, and compare the seconds. `strtotime` may work, but you'll need to run it on `$diff` too before comparing.

Comment: What did not ? Converting numbers to seconds and comparing them afterwards ? I doubt it.

Comment: if (strtotime($diff) > strtotime("072:00:00") )

{
echo $b . "existing script";
}
else
if (strtotime($diff) < strtotime("08:00:00"))
{
echo $b . "DB";
}
else if( strtotime($diff) > strtotime("08:00:00") && strtotime($diff) < strtotime("072:00:00"))
{
echo $b . "DB URL";
} this i have done but still it didnot work

Comment: please see my above comment its the code I have done but it did not work

Comment: Actually, nobody seems to know what the `072:00:00` means. If my world, hours goes from 0 to 23.

Comment: so what should I do in this case? should I multiple the 72  hours into seconds then compare?please guide me

Comment: If you want to compare length, then my answer apply. Multiply the hours by 3600, minutes by 60 and add them together with seconds, then compare them.

Comment: if ($diff > strtotime("00:00:259200") )

{
echo "existing script";
}
else
if ($diff < strtotime("08:00:00"))
{
echo "DB";
}
else if( $diff > strtotime("08:00:00") && $diff < strtotime("00:00:259200"))
{
echo  "DB URL";
} this seems to work for me

Comment: Convert all of them, and stop using strtotime, use Int. Comments are no a place for discussion, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, $diff is a string not an int, it should be:

```
$diff = strtotime("22:32:53");
```

Comparing is usually done using [DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

The comparison will not work anyway because if you check

```
var_dump(strtotime("072:00:00"));
```

will return:

```
false
```

strtotime is trying to match the format against a known time format, and 72 is not a valid hour.